# AngularJs : $scope is in $apply phase ,still $http request is not sending immediately?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am sending Http request . But its not immediately fire.And i already checked that its scope is in $apply phase. So any one have idea that Why this one is happening??

My service like:

```
changeUserRole : function (groupId,roleObj) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post("groups/" + groupId , roleObj)
                 .success(function (result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                 }).error(function (error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                 })

            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

`

I try to debug it , And in that its go on `$http.post("")` line And then on `return deferred.promise`, But not fire any request.

Thank You in advance!!

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? The success of error callback will only be invoked when the HTTP response comes from the server. Not necessary when the next $apply() is executed.

Comment: I want that when i called changeUserRole function , $http request must be fire immediately.But here its not working.

Comment: And how do you determine that the request is not fired?